# Jeet comes with _jeet.styl but jeet.styl is required

Tags: npm, gulp

We use gulp and jeet in our project. However, for some reason jeet comes with a file node_modules/jeet/stylus/jeet/_jeet.styl and running gulp install crashes because jeet.styl (without underscore) is required. Copying the file or renaming it resolves the issue locally, but with our ci servers and deploy automation this is a real pain!

Here's an excerpt from out package.json

```
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-bower": "0.0.10",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-stylus": "^2.0.6",
"gulp-typescript": "^2.13.0",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.4.1",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
"jeet": "^6.1.2",
```

And this is what we get from gulp install:

```
   Error: path_to_proj\client\styles\screen.styl:168:21
   164|     padding-bottom 6em
   165|
   166|   code
   167|     font-weight bold
   168|     color light-gray
----------------------------^

failed to locate @import file jeet.styl

at Evaluator.visitImport (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:915:21)
at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\index.js:28:40)
at Evaluator.visit (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:160:18)
at Evaluator.visitRoot (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:707:27)
at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\index.js:28:40)
at Evaluator.visit (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:160:18)
at Evaluator.evaluate (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:247:15)
at Renderer.render (path_to_proj\node_modules\stylus\lib\renderer.js:86:26)
at dispatch (path_to_proj\node_modules\when\node.js:71:15)
at callAndResolve (path_to_proj\node_modules\when\lib\apply.js:30:12)
```

Any ideas why that underscore file ends up in there and how to make things work?

Comment: I've added an ncp command to postinstall to get past this problem but the original cause is still unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm install left something out, being a node noob, I don't know how to fix it!

But this solution works:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jeet
$ sudo ln -s styl/index.styl ./jeet.styl
$ sudo vi style/index.styl
```

and prepend 'styl/' to each of the '@import' lines in index.styl

Comment: Somehow the newer configuration I have just works. Marking this as the solution since until now I managed with similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jeet = require('jeet');

var options = { use: [jeet()] };

.pipe(stylus(options))
```